# Updating Screen when new data is received - React Native EXPO

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm trying to figure out how to reload a screen when new data is received.

The problem is, I have a 'Search' screen where users can search for different players which initiates API call and stores data in AsyncStorage,

when my Profile screen is loaded I call useEffect to retrieve this data and then display appropriate information. This worked just fine when using stack navigator but since moving to tab navigation (preferred way) Profile screen only updates the first time when it's displayed.

So if user goes back to 'Search' screen and searches for different data nothing changes in 'Profile' screen until the user restarts the app.

I'm using Expo (not sure if that makes difference, but I'm very new to javascript / react coming from Swift and C#),

I've found couple possibilities like componentWillMount but that doesn't seem to work correctly with the way I have my screens set up.

Below is example code of how my screens are built (i've seen variations with class which is likely reason why componentDidMount didn't work) as placing the whole screen would make it too confusing.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

const Profile = () => {

    return(
        <View>
           <Text>Profile<Text/>
        </View>
    )

}

export default Profile
```

Adding full code per request:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, Button, Text, Image, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, FlatList,AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import useLeague from '../hooks/useLeague';
import useMatchHistory from '../hooks/useMatchHistory';
import MatchItem from '../components/MatchItem';
import useMatchDetailArray from '../hooks/useMatchDetailArray';
import matchHistory from '../api/matchHistory';
import {SafeAreaView} from 'react-navigation';

const Profile = () => {
var id = ''
var puuid = ''







const [searchLeague, results, errorMessage] = useLeague()
const [searchMatchHistory, matchHistoryVar, errorMessageMatchHistory] = useMatchHistory()
const [searchArray,matchDetailArray] = useMatchDetailArray()


useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('puuid', (err, result) => {
        //SET ID = SUMMONER ID
        puuid = result

            AsyncStorage.getItem('summonerID', (err, summonerIDResult) => {
                console.log(`Data found: ` + summonerIDResult);
                id = summonerIDResult

                console.log('ID: ' + id + 'PUUID:' + puuid)
                searchLeague(id);
                searchMatchHistory(puuid);

            });



    });


}, []);


if(results[0]==null) {
    return(
        <View>
            <Text>Waiting for data</Text>
        </View>
    )
} else {
    //this renders only if profile data was loaded
    const profile = results[0];
    var path = require('../../assets/SILVER.png')

    switch (profile.tier) {
        case 'CHALLENGER': 
            path = require('../../assets/CHALLENGER.png')
            break;
        case 'GRANDMASTER': 
            path = require('../../assets/GRANDMASTER.png')
            break;
        case 'MASTER': 
            path = require('../../assets/MASTER.png')
            break;
        case 'DIAMOND': 
            path = require('../../assets/DIAMOND.png')
            break;
        case 'PLATINUM': 
            path = require('../../assets/PLATINUM.png')
            break;
        case 'GOLD': 
            path = require('../../assets/GOLD.png')
            break;
        case 'SILVER': 
            path = require('../../assets/SILVER.png')
            break;
        case 'IRON': 
            path = require('../../assets/IRON.png')
            break;
        default: 
            path = require('../../assets/BRONZE.png')

    }

    return(
        <SafeAreaView style={{backgroundColor: 'white', flex: 1}}>
            <View style= {styles.header}>
                <Image style= {styles.tier} source={path}/>
                <View style={styles.headerSubView}>
                    <Text style = {styles.lp}>{profile.leaguePoints} LP</Text>
                    <Text style = {styles.division}>Division {profile.rank}</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.mainContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome, {profile.summonerName}!</Text>



                 <SafeAreaView style={styles.flatView}>

                    <TouchableOpacity 
                        style={styles.matchHistory}
                        onPress={() => {
                            searchArray(matchHistoryVar)
                        }}
                        > 
                        <Text style= {styles.leagueRanking}>{`Match History (${matchHistoryVar.length})`}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>


                     <FlatList
                    style={styles.flatList}
                    data={matchDetailArray}
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                    keyExtractor= {(result) => Math.random().toString()}
                    renderItem={({item}) => {
                    return <MatchItem 
                    match_id = {item.metadata.match_id}
                    units = {item.info.participants[0].units}
                    queue_id = {item.info.queue_id}
                    content_ID = {item.info.participants[0].companion.content_ID}
                    game_datetime = {item.info.game_datetime}
                    placement={item.info.participants[0].placement} 
                    level={item.info.participants[0].level} 
                    time_eliminated={item.info.participants[0].time_eliminated} 
                    last_round= {item.info.participants[0].last_round}/>
                    }}/>

                </SafeAreaView>




            </SafeAreaView>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

}
```

Comment: Can you share the code that you're using for displaying the data the first time?

Comment: all the data comes from api and is stores in state so not sure and then I'm calling parts of the object to display it's values, but I'll edit to add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) with [reduxsauce](https://github.com/jkeam/reduxsauce) (to organize things). It helps you to behave your application consistently by updating states globally. It is a bit of a steep learning curve but it solves the problem on this world of stateful components.